# What are the security implication of implementing an IVR functionality in my application?

Tags: phone, risk

I am planning to implement an Interactive Voice Recognition (IVR) functionality in my python-based application. I will be using IVR as a backup verification method or when a user is going to setup her 2FA for the first time.

**What are the security consideration of implementing an IVR functionality that I need to consider in my application?**

I've found a few articles like the below, but they only talk about implementation and nothing around the security:

- https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/07/build-an-ivr-system-with-twilio-and-django.html
- https://github.com/plivo/phone-ivr-python